# The application does not work after the deploy?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bitrix

When I try to use the [vue-custom-component](https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element), I get an error on the vue-router

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import vueCustomElement from 'vue-custom-element';
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import Element from 'element-ui'
import elementLocale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/ru-RU'
import VueFullPage from 'vue-fullpage.js'

import Testing from '@/components/Testing.vue'

Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
  'example-component'
];

// Enable the plugin
Vue.use(vueCustomElement);

// Register your component
Vue.customElement('example-component', Testing, {
  // Additional Options: https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element#options
});

Vue.use(Element, { locale: elementLocale });
Vue.use(VueFullPage);
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';
import './assets/css/fonts.scss';
import './assets/css/main.scss';
import 'animate.css';

<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><head><meta charset=utf-8><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge"><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link rel=icon href=/favicon.ico><title>testing_baziron_vorobjev</title><link href=./css/app.1fe0df1e.css rel=preload as=style><link href=./css/chunk-vendors.9205998e.css rel=preload as=style><link href=./js/app.10a7c671.js rel=preload as=script><link href=./js/chunk-vendors.9cb8b2ec.js rel=preload as=script><link href=./css/chunk-vendors.9205998e.css rel=stylesheet><link href=./css/app.1fe0df1e.css rel=stylesheet></head><body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but testing doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript><example-component></example-component><script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/document-register-element/1.4.1/document-register-element.js"></script><script src=./js/chunk-vendors.9cb8b2ec.js></script><script src=./js/app.10a7c671.js></script></body></html>
```

I used the vue-cli3. Made a small application;
I did everything on instructions; After the command NPM rub build jump errors

[image]

The application itself is being downloaded. But errors appear. And if I corrected the picture errors, then the first one I can not fix

Comment: Hi. Please ask your question in english and provide more details :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Comment: Can you show the part of the application where you're using `<router-view>..</router-view>`?